# Admin restricted pages not redirecting to the admin login page Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

Recently upgraded from Laravel 6 to Laravel 7, the problem I'm having is when I use the url /admin it should redirect to the admin login page this also applies to admin restricted pages if the user isn't logged in. I'm not sure if I need to change something to the routes in my web.php file or in the login controller.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'module' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => ['web'], 'namespace' => 'Admin\Controllers'], function() {

    // Login and Logout Routes
    Route::get('login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm']);
    Route::post('login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@login']);
    Route::post('logout', ['as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@logout']);

    // Password Reset Routes
    Route::post('password/email', ['as' => 'password.email', 'uses' => 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail']);
    Route::get('password/reset', ['as' => 'password.request', 'uses' => 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm']);
    Route::post('password/reset', ['as' => '', 'uses' => 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset'])->name('password.update');
    Route::get('password/reset/{token}', ['as' => 'password.reset', 'uses' => 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm']);
});
```

Login Controller

```
    protected $redirectTo = '/admin';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('Admin::auth.login');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue has an error in my terminal Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255. Which means I forgot to do the upgrade for this https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#symfony-5-related-upgrades.